# Severe memory leak with Django

Tags: django, memory-leaks, server

I am facing a problem of huge memory leak on a server, serving a Django (1.8) app with Apache or Ngnix (The issue happens on both).

When I go on certain pages (let's say on the specific request below) the RAM of the server goes up to 16 G in few seconds (with only one request) and the server freeze.

```
def records(request):
    """Return list 14 last records page. """
    values = []
    time = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=14)
    record =Records.objetcs.filter(time__gte=time)
    return render(request,
                  'record_app/records_newests.html',
                  {
                      'active_nav_tab': ["active", "", "", ""]
                      ' record': record, 
                  })
```

When I git checkout to older version, back when there was no such problem, the problem survives and i have the same issue.

I Did a memory check with Gumpy for the faulty request here is the result:

```
>>> hp.heap()
Partition of a set of 7042 objects. Total size = 8588675016 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0   1107  16 8587374512 100 8587374512 100 unicode
     1   1014  14   258256   0 8587632768 100 django.utils.safestring.SafeText
     2     45   1   150840   0 8587783608 100 dict of 0x390f0c0
     3    281   4    78680   0 8587862288 100 dict of django.db.models.base.ModelState
     4    326   5    75824   0 8587938112 100 list
     5     47   1    49256   0 8587987368 100 dict of 0x38caad0
     6     47   1    49256   0 8588036624 100 dict of 0x39ae590
     7     46   1    48208   0 8588084832 100 dict of 0x3858ab0
     8     46   1    48208   0 8588133040 100 dict of 0x38b8450
     9     46   1    48208   0 8588181248 100 dict of 0x3973fe0
<164 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Comment: There isn't any information on here for us to go on, something you've added to those "certain" pages, requires a lot of memory

Comment: You need to restart the server after reverting to the previous version of the code.

Comment: So when an issue is complicated you just put it on hold on ? Whatever thing i put on those "certain" pages is gone since I git checked out to a previous commit. And I am certain that this older commit hadn't the issue because this server is used by a lot of persons every day.

Comment: And for the "restart the server" I tryed of course. I even deployed on nginx (I was using apache first.) and the problem is still there

Comment: When I execute the view corresponding to one of the problematic page I get no problem so the issue is not a SQL request or in the code of the view.

Comment: Maybe some custom middleware that blows up the HttpResponse?

Comment: How can I check or investigate this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of search I found my answer.

While investigating I checked statistics on my DB and saw that some table was 800Mo big but had only 900 rows. This table contains a Textfield without max len. Somehow one text field got a huge amount of data inserted into and this line was slowing everything down on every pages using this model.